# barryvdh laravel dompdf rendering just two pages

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5, dompdf

I am using [barryvdh laravel dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/) for rendering pdf from html view in laravel 5.7. It was working fine but when the view exceeds to more than 2 pages it cuts the page and does not print the third page. However if i copy all the page data and paste it somewhere else the who content is pasted which means the content is there somehow but not showing.

This [issue](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/504) was also mentioned in the github repository but was not answered by anyone.

I am using Laravel 5.7

This is code :

```
    $pdf = PDF::loadview('emails.send-email.case-email-pdf', compact('pdf_data'));


    $file_name = 'case-email-'.$data['case_id'].str_random(10).time().'.pdf';

    Storage::put($config['folder'].'/'.$file_name,$pdf->output());
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a solution for you, but you can try putting some parts in divs and try `page-break-inside:avoid;` on these divs. Playing around with the page breaks helped me multiple times when being stuck in domPDF with weird behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to NOT USE table tag. Use divs instead.

Comment: Nice solution. But I figure out something else. I just wrote some inappropriate syntax inside `table` tag accidentally,  and it worked for me.

`
<table>
<tr>

<td> My Data </td>
<td> My Data </td>

Some dummy data with `display: none;` 

</tr>

</table>
`

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't love this answer, but the problem in my case was a long table contained within a second table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h1>Heading</h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <table>
                [lots and lots of data]
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If I moved the long table outside of the container table, everything worked fine:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h1>Heading</h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    [lots and lots of data]
</table>
```

(I know making a "heading" table for an h1 is overkill; in my case the heading table contained a bunch of formatted-ish data in rows and columns, hence the need for a table.)